# Tapestry - Spring - Cannot Initialize Context

Tags: java, spring, junit, tapestry

I am relatively new in Tapesty/Spring.

I am trying to set up the test suit for an application that i was handed at.
The application works correctly and the Tapesty/Spring/Hibernate all are fine.

So i am just creating a simple test

```
package reservations.services.restaurant;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.mytableguru.backend.reservation.service.ReservationService;
import com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.enums.DayOfTheWeekEnum;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml" })
public class RestaurantTableAvailabilityServiceImplTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Inject
    private ReservationService reservationService;

    @Test
    public void testContext() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(reservationService);
    }
}
```

with the following test-applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mytableguru" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
</beans>
```

and when i am trying to launch the test i get the following error

```
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:37 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@4439f31e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@5dfcfece, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@23ceabc1, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5d5eef3d]
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [test-applicationContext.xml]
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5f341870: startup date [Wed Mar 02 16:07:38 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [database.properties]
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:39 PM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:39 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:39 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> z8kfsx9fffxf5413o5389|71652c98, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kfsx9fffxf5413o5389|71652c98, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/reservations, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
INFO 3/2/16 4:07 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 3/2/16 4:07 PM: liquibase: Reading from public.databasechangelog
INFO 3/2/16 4:07 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.show_sql=false, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.use_sql_comments=true}
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.model.MenuSection
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.model.MenuSection
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.mytableguru.backend.reservation.model.ReservationTable
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.mytableguru.backend.reservation.model.ReservationTable
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:41 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:42 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantFileUploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantService com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantFileUploadServiceImpl.restaurantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Mar 02, 2016 4:07:42 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@23ceabc1] to prepare test instance [reservations.services.restaurant.RestaurantTableAvailabilityServiceImplTest@39ab5ef7]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantFileUploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantService com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantFileUploadServiceImpl.restaurantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantService com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantFileUploadServiceImpl.restaurantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 56 more
```

I just cant seem to figure out how to connect my application with the JUnit and have them connected correctly with Spring etc.

Any ideas please  ?

Edit 1 : 
Thank you Lance for the input
I have tried the following

```
@RunWith(TapestryIOCJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Registry(modules = { TapestryModule.class, AppModule.class })
public class RestaurantTableAvailabilityServiceImplTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @ModuleDef
    public static SpringModuleDef createSpringModuleDef() {
        final ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml");
        ServletContext sc = new MockServletContext();
        return new SpringModuleDef(sc) {
            @Override
            protected ApplicationContext locateApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
                return appContext;
            }
        };
    }
```

but it will not pass

```
final ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml");
```

i seem to still get an error

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantFileUploadServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantService com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantFileUploadServiceImpl.restaurantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restaurantServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource com.mytableguru.backend.restaurant.service.RestaurantServiceImpl.assetSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.apache.tapestry5.services.AssetSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject(), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create a SpringModuleDef to mimmic the [TapestrySpringFilter](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/master/tapestry-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/spring/TapestrySpringFilter.java)

Instead of the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, it's likely easiest to use the TapestryIOCJUnit4ClassRunner (see [here](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/master/tapestry-ioc-junit/src/test/java/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/junit/TapestryIOCJUnit4ClassRunnerModuleDefTest.java) for an example)

eg:

```
@RunWith(TapestryIOCJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Registry(modules={TapestryModule.class, HibernateCoreModule.class, SomeOtherModule.class})
public class MyTest {
    @ModuleDef
    public static SpringModuleDef createSpringModuleDef() {
         final ApplicationContext appContext = new XMLApplicationContext("classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml");
         ServletContext sc = new MockServletContext();
         return new SpringModuleDef(sc) {
             protected ApplicationContext locateApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
                 return appContext;
             }
         };
    }

    @Inject
    private Foo someSpringBean;

    @Inject
    private Bar someTapestryBean;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've never used tapestry's spring integration. I'm guessing somewhere in your code there's a contribution to ApplicationContextCustomizer?

The documentation [here](https://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-spring-framework.html#IntegratingwithSpringFramework-InjectingTapestryservicesinSpringbeans) states that

> If you have configured Spring to allow annotation-based injection,
>   then you will be able to inject Tapestry services into your Spring
>   Beans. This feature is only available when Spring ApplicationContext
>   is not configured and loaded externally.

Here's something else to try:

```
@RunWith(TapestryIOCJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Registry(modules={TapestryModule.class, SpringModule.class, TestModule.class})
public class MyTest {
    public static class TestModule {
        @Contribute(ApplicationContextCustomizer.class)
        public static void addCustomizer(OrderedConfiguration<ApplicationContextCustomizer> config) {
            ApplicationContextCustomizer customizer = new ApplicationContextCustomizer() {
                public void customizeApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext, ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                    applicationContext.setConfigLocation("classpath:/test-applicationContext.xml");
                }
            };
            config.add("mycustomizer", customizer);
        }
    }


    @ModuleDef
    public static SpringModuleDef createSpringModuleDef() {
        ServletContext sc = new MockServletContext();
        return new SpringModuleDef(sc);
    } 

   // @Inject @Test etc
```